# How to access key from nested object in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can you please help me how can I access "name" key from obj3. Please find below example.

I am looking for good approch, I dont want to do :

obj.obj1.obj2.obj3.name

```
var obj = {
    obj1 : {
        obj2: {
            obj3: {
                name: 'jhon'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: and what do you want instead of dot notation?

Comment: there are only two ways to acces object properties `dot notation` and `bracket notation` ex `obj.key` or `obj[key]`.

Comment: if any function is there in javascript or any other approach.

Comment: if its just about accessing the property then i would say no there no other way.

Comment: okay, thanks manish!!!

Comment: @manish there are a few. However, its not really useful in this case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could theoretically destructure using es6 for example

`const {obj1: {obj2: { obj3: {name: b}}}} = obj
 console.log(b) //jhon`

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you please explain a bit.

Comment: Take note there is no dot notation here.

Comment: This will be enough to get you going. [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) . You should also mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function that returns the first non object element.

Obviously this functions works only for structures where the nested objects contains only one object or one value.

```
var obj = {
    obj1 : {
        obj2: {
            obj3: {
                name: 'jhon'
            }
        }
    }
}

const getName = (obj) => {
    if (typeof obj[Object.keys(obj)] === 'object') {
        return  getName(obj[Object.keys(obj)])
    } else {
        return obj[Object.keys(obj)]
    }
}

getName(obj)
```